# Coordinates from a KML file not displayed properly in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a KML file and I extract the last coordinates and try to set them as a center of a Google Map but the marker is in a completely different place .

Do I have to "convert" KML coordinates into google maps coordinates ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you dont "convert" you "project" and the answer is "maybe"

Comment: Add an actual example. Otherwise really 'maybe' is about the best answer you can get.

Comment: I don't understand actually because everything works properly. The kml file is displayed correctly on the map and when I display the coordinates copied from the kml file the marker is displayed in the wrong place (but it is displayed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KML coordinates are x,y (longitude, latitude), whereas Maps uses LatLng (or y,x / latitude, longitude).

Just switch the x and y order and you should be all set.