# Get coordinates from KML feed to use with mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kml, foursquare, mapbox

I'm trying to get the coordinates from my foursquare feed and use them in a map to display on a website. Mostly as an exercise to learn javascript and Mapbox – I'm new to this.

I've used the mapbox 'add single marker' code and some other code to cycle through my KML to find the coordinates, [since mapbox does not accept the KML](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/general-questions/8523-can-kml-point-data-be-read-directly-into-mapbox).

Somehow, I can't get it to work. Any tips are much appreciated!

```
<!-- Foursquare map -->
<script>

    // get coordinates and place from Foursquare feed
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.get("https://feeds.foursquare.com/history/6a46a109e06aa6d74d34b42b397806d5.kml?count=1", function(data){

            $(data).find("Placemark").each(function(index, value){

                coords = $(this).find("coordinates").text();
                place = $(this).find("name").text();
                pos = coords.split(",")

                    var features = [{
                        "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": pos[0], pos[1]},
                        "properties": { "place": place }       
                    }];
            });
        });
    });        

    // start Mapbox
    var map = mapbox.map('map-canvas').zoom(5).center({
        lat: 0,
        lon: 0
        });

  map.addLayer(mapbox.layer().id('rikwuts.map-0i5jiwdn'));

  // Create an empty markers layer
  var markerLayer = mapbox.markers.layer().features(features);

  // Add interaction to this marker layer. This
  // binds tooltips to each marker that has title
  // and description defined.
  mapbox.markers.interaction(markerLayer);
  map.addLayer(markerLayer);

  // Add a single feature to the markers layer.
  // You can use .features() to add multiple features.
  markerLayer.add_feature({
      geometry: {
          // The order of coordinates here is lon, lat. This is because
          // we use the GeoJSON specification for all marker features.
          // (lon, lat is also the internal order of KML and other geographic formats)
          coordinates: [ pos.lng, pos.lat ]
      },
      properties: {
          // these properties customize the look of the marker
          // see the simplestyle-spec for a full reference:
          // https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec
          'marker-color': '#00ff00',
          'marker-symbol': 'star-stroked',
          title: place,
          description: 'This is a single marker.'
      }
  });

  // Attribute map
  map.ui.attribution.add()
      .content('<a href="http://mapbox.com/about/maps">Thanks to Mapbox</a>');
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- END map -->
```

Comment: one problem: looks like your coordinates are in the wrong order [Coordinates from a KML file not displayed properly in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866925/coordinates-from-a-kml-file-not-displayed-properly-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toGeoJSON](https://github.com/tmcw/togeojson) to convert KML into GeoJSON for MapBox.js.